# What is a suitable testing framework for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am working with Ruby On Rails for the last year. But, could not work on Unit Testing. Now I have to write a unit testing code. Which testing framework is good and why?

Is there any good tutorial for this?

My system configuration: Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3, Ubuntu 10

Comment: Yes, there are a few questions with zero answers. I went through some of the answers as you asked me to and have left my comments on them.

Answer (score 0):

The first tip is: Try upgrading to Rails 5.x. This is good practice to always leave your system clean and faultless from third parties.

Your greatest friend will always be the rails documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/testing.html

In last case if you can not upgrade, you can use the Minitest/Rspec gems, in old versions compatible with the current versions of development.

To perform integration testing you can try using Capybara or Google Chrome Headless.

You can look at how some big projects do tests, like the RubyGems site, which is written in RoR and is open in Github: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org

Answer (score 0):

I am using Rspec from last two years and from my point of view it is easiest testing framework for Ruby that I have used.

In Rspec, you have to create objects of your models using `factories` and use it in script.

There are only 3 - blocks to write in Rspec : `describe`, `context` and `it`.

Refer - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/model-specs

Comment: One can argue that minitest is the easiest one. It does not require learning factories and any new DSL. "It's just ruby".

Comment: Yes, but I am using `rspec` from two years and still I am using it, also if there is any issue related to rspec, then solution will get easily on stack overflow .